# Importing same object in renderer as in main process

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I have a custom class in separate file `discovery.ts` where my code looks like this

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
class Discovery extends EventEmitter {
   let myProperty = 'value';

   constructor { super(); }
}
let disc = new Discovery();
export { disc };
```

Now I have a `main.ts` file representing Electron's main process:

```
import { app, Tray, Menu, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, screen } from 'electron';
import { disc } from './discovery';

let window: Electron.BrowserWindow = null;
app.on('ready', () => {
  ////
  disc.myProperty = 'new value'; // Changing value here
  ////

  window = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/../html/index.html';);
});
```

And a `index.ts` file representing Electron's renderer process (this file is imported as a script from `index.html`):

```
import { disc } from './discovery';
console.log(disc.myProperty); // Should print 'new value' but prints 'value'
```

Now the problem is that I want `Discovery` class to be a same object across all files that import `'./discovery'` but when I assign a new value to `disc.myProperty` in `main.ts` the `console.log(disc.myProperty)` in `index.ts` still prints an old value - 'value'.

From what I understood I thought that modules are executed only once so when you import a object in multiple files you import the same object in each file and the state of this object is same in all files. Am I wrong? Or could this problem be related to Electron?

Comment: You can share an instance across processes.

Comment: @SLaks could you please show me or point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry; I mean you can't.

Comment: so the only way to achieve something similar to this is to communicate with `main.ts` using `ipcRenderer` from `index.ts` and then delegate the demand to `Discovery` from `main.ts`?

Comment: Hey @Superian007 - I think I just stuck on the same issue... Any chance to recall the right way to go? :D this one from the previous comment or something else? Tnx